# What correct way to close pjsip app?

Tags: c++, sip, pjsip

I wrote the simple app base on pjsip (pjsua2).
If I close my app when I have active calls I have memory access error in Endpoint::on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)

I try before closing do

```
Endpoint::instance().hangupAllCalls();
pj_thread_sleep(2000);
```

Some time 2 sec enough time for closing and app closed correctly, but some time doesn't.

What correct way to close the pjsua2 app?
And how waiting what all calls are hangup?

Answer (score 1):

From my expirience of working with PJSUA2, the correct way to exit is to ensure that destructors of all calls are called before pj::Account destructor and desturctor for pj::Account is called before pj::Endpoint destructor.

In my applications I have integer calls counter and exit bool flag in pj::Account derived class like:

```
class MyAccount : public pj::Account
{
public:
    ...
    void incrementCallsCount() { ++_callsCount; }
    void decrementCallsCount() { --_callsCount; }
    size_t getCallsCount() const { return _callsCount; }
    ...
    void setWantExit(boot wantExitFlag) { _wantExitFlag = wantExitFlag; }
    void onIncomingCall(pj::OnIncomingCallParam &prm)
    {
       if (_wantExitFlag)
           return;
       MyCall *call = MyCall::create(*this, prm.callId);
       // Do your stuff with call:
       // - add to map id->call
       // - answer SIP 180 Ringing / SIP 200 OK
    }
    ...
private:
    std::atomic<size_t> _callsCount;
    bool _wantExitFlag;
};
```

In constructor of pj::Call derived class I call incrementCallsCount() and in destructor I call decrementCallsCount() like:

```
class MyCall : public pj::Call
{
public:
    typedef pj::Call base_class;
    static MyCall *create(MyAccount &account, int callId)
    {
        return new MyCall(account, callId);
    }

    virtual void onCallState(pj::OnCallStateParam& prm)
    {
        pj::CallInfo ci = getInfo();
        if (ci.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED)
        {
            // You may call some onDisconnected() handler function here
            delete this;
            return;
        }
    }
    ...
private:
    MyCall(MyAccount &account, int callId)
        : base_class(account, callId)
        , _myAccount(account)
    {
        _myAccount.incrementCallsCount();
    }

    virtual ~MyCall()
    {
        _myAccount.decrementCallsCount();
    }

    MyAccount &_myAccount;
};
```

Note that constructor and destructor declared as private, to ensure that users create calls by static fuction MyCall::create() only! MyCall class takes responsibility for memory management: call deleted only when PJSUA2 tells to delete call (`PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED` call state).

With this functions and classes in mind, if you just want to exit from application almost immediately, you should:

- Stop creating MyCall in MyAccount by `_myAccount.setWantExit(true)`. When `pj::Call::onIncomingCall()` function returns immediately, PJSUA2 hande this by executing hangup() for the call immediately.
- call `Endpoint::instance().hangupAllCalls()`
- wait until `MyAccount::getCallsCount()` will return 0
- ensure MyAccount's destructor is called before Enpoint's destructor
- exit application

Comment: Thank's with pleasure for answers, I take your principles and try if I return to this project.

Comment: Actually, instead just stopping to receive incoming calls in my applications I answer with `SIP 302 Moved Temporarily` to other instances of SIP-telephony (I have distributed installation). But it is not necessary point of my answer. Good luck!